# Tried to apply css to a component conditionally using prop but its not working

Tags: html, css, vue.js, prop

```css
.storyMobile{
color:green;
}
.storyWeb{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="storyMobile">
hii
</div>
<div class="storyWeb">
hii
</div>


//main view

  <div>
        <story   :story="stories[0]"/>
  </div>


//here it prints stories in red colour but I want it to be displayed in green colour - how can I do this?
```

This is my component where I have 2 divs with 2 different classes one will be active for mobile and one will be active for web.

```
<div class="storyMobile">
//code
</div>

 <div class="storyWeb">
//code
</div>
```

//this is my main view where I am importing this component

```
<div class="body-frame">
    <Header></Header>
    <section class="content-section-bar" v-if="stories && stories.length">

      <div>
        <story   :story="stories[0]"/>
      </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

By default the story component is in web so "storyweb" class is getting applied to it but I want the "storyweb" class to get applied on it.

How should I do it in vue.js I tried using the props but didn't get the desired output.

Comment: can you show full code or give a simple example in snippet?

Comment: attached, basically i have 2 classes bydefault class 1 is getting applied but i want the class 2 to be applied

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

your component:

```
<div :class="className"></div>
```

script:

```
export default {
  props: {
    className: {
      default: 'storyWeb'
    }
  }
}
```

usage:

```
<story :story="stories[0]"/>
<story :story="stories[0]" class-name="storyMobile"/>
```

```js
Vue.component('story',{
  template: `<div :class="className">test</div>`,
  props: {
    className: {
      type: String,
      default: 'storyWeb'
    },
    story: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      stories: [
        {content: 'sotry1 content'},
        {content: 'story2 content'}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.storyMobile{
  color:green;
}
.storyWeb{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <story :story="stories[0]" class-name="storyMobile"></story>
  <story :story="stories[1]"></story>
</div>
```

Comment: nothing happened it still appears in its default manner that is web

Comment: I've wrote a simple example,have a look.